# iframe z-index in ie8

Tags: for-loop, z-index, bgiframe

Hi sorry every one my English is not good! I am using an iframe for a video. Above the iframe there is a dropdown menu, it is working well in firefox but in ie8 dropdown goes to underneath the iframe. If I replace the iframe with an image it is working good. I have play with position and z-index properties a long day but there is no use. Please help me if there any solution for avoiding this issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your video is being played by Flash....

If you're embedding Flash you should explicitely set the wmode parameter to opaque to avoid dropdowns diving behind the flash object.  You could also use a [library](http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/flashembed.html) to deal with the nasty details of embedding flash in different browsers.

EDIT:  instead of including an iframe try this - took your movie and used the embedding link youtube presents at the end of the movie:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Embedded YT Movie with DIV element on top</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <object style="height: 390px; width: 640px">
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/zFJfbDETIIk?version=3">
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque"> <!-- I added this one wrt youtube's proposed URL -->
            <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/zFJfbDETIIk?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                   allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390" 
                   wmode="opaque" <!-- I added this one wrt youtube's proposed URL -->
                   >
        </object>
        <div style="position:absolute;width:300px;height:300px;top:10px;left:10px;background-color: red;">
            This one should be on top.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I am not using flash embedded just I am using iframe for displaying a video. My code is like.<iframe width="560" height="386" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zFJfbDETIIk" style="z-index:1;position:relative;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> and this is my site url:file:///F:/projects/CJSolutions/html/1243.html

Comment: pull that URL into IE8, the video will start.  Press F12 for developer tools and you'll see the flash player wrapped in div id=watch-player-div.  So it's a flash movie you're embedding after all, albeit indirectly.

Comment: Yes it is working in ie really thanks a lot I am so happy with your response! Thanks again and again. I have spent total one day for this issue! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Excellent!  May I point out that it is common practice here to *accept* an answer?  please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for instructions